# set generic alert for all instances in an auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to set alert for metric disk_inodes_free for all the instances in an auto scaling group. would putting * for instanceid work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Some metrics are automatically generated for an Auto Scaling group so that you can measure, for example, `CPUUtilization` as an average across all instances. This can be used to trigger scaling. However, I don't think you can create additional metrics that apply to all instances of an Auto Scaling group.

Nor does the average of inodes_free make sense across multiple instances, since it is only relevant to the specific instances that are low on free nodes. If you had one instance with lots of free nodes and another with zero free nodes, an 'average of' alarm would not be triggered. You'll really want a separate alarm on each instance.